# Problem with org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite and tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, url-rewriting

I'am developing an application with spring roo, and i must deploy it in a tomcat 5.5. At developing time I use jetty and have no problem, but when I test it in tomcat all my urls are wrong and I get this log message.

```
DEBUG http-8080-3 org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
ERROR http-8080-3 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[default] - Servlet.service() para servlet default lanzó excepción
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:713)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.WildcardMatcher.replaceAll(WildcardMatcher.java:118)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase.matchesBase(RuleBase.java:242)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRule.matches(NormalRule.java:88)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRuleProcessing(RuleChain.java:79)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.process(RuleChain.java:133)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:140)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
```

I realise that is a problem with url rewrite when it try to replace with regex the symbol $. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is a clue http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/issues/detail?id=71

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem using next version of urlrewrite

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewrite</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```